# How can i redirect some url in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on word press blog
I want to redirect some old URL to new one's.
My old URL was `www.example.com/blog/category/subcategory/post`. 
Now i want to redirect all these types of URL to `www.example.com/blog/Post`. 
I have tried redirect in ht-access of sub domain but i didn't worked.

```
Redirect 301 category/subcategory/test_post/ www.example.com/blog/test_post/
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with http:// before the last url? I believe that is required.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea with htaccess was correct. You will have to implement this via the Apache Conf. So htaccess will add its content to the Apache configuration.

However, not all Apache servers are configured to accept all htaccess commands.

So, please check your main Apache config if it allows to override anything and if the redirect module is enabled.

Also note, that it is not a good idea to write host names in capital letters, as they may be case sensitive. www != WWW

As for the syntax, you might need to include the protocol.

```
Redirect permanent /one http://www.newdomain.com/two
```